# ERROR: relation "table" does not exist, even though both the database and the table exist

Tags: cockroachdb

I'm using cockroachdb, which is essentially a superset of postgres and I can't understand why the statement:

```
select * from _a66df261120b6c23.tabDefaultValue;
```

results sin the error:

```
ERROR: relation "_a66df261120b6c23.tabdefaultvalue" does not exist
```

`show databases` gives me:

```
    database_name   | owner | primary_region | regions | survival_goal
--------------------+-------+----------------+---------+----------------
  _a66df261120b6c23 | root  | NULL           | {}      | NULL
  defaultdb         | root  | NULL           | {}      | NULL
  postgres          | root  | NULL           | {}      | NULL
  root              | root  | NULL           | {}      | NULL
  sammy             | root  | NULL           | {}      | NULL
  system            | node  | NULL           | {}      | NULL
  test123           | root  | NULL           | {}      | NULL
  test3             | root  | NULL           | {}      | NULL
  test4             | root  | NULL           | {}      | NULL
  test5             | root  | NULL           | {}      | NULL
  test9             | root  | NULL           | {}      | NULL
```

and `show tables from _a66df261120b6c23` gives me:

```
  schema_name |    table_name     | type  | owner | estimated_row_count | locality
--------------+-------------------+-------+-------+---------------------+-----------
  public      | __Auth            | table | root  |                   0 | NULL
  public      | tabDefaultValue   | table | root  |                   0 | NULL
```

The database and the table both exist, so why does `select * from _a66df261120b6c23.tabDefaultValue;` fail? Strange thing is when I run `\dt` all I get is:

```
  schema_name | table_name | type  | owner | estimated_row_count | locality
--------------+------------+-------+-------+---------------------+-----------
  public      | sammy      | table | root  |                   0 | NULL
```

How do I actually get the `select` statement to work? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL statements are case sensitive and incoming identifiers are lowercased unless specifically [forced with double quotes](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/keywords-and-identifiers.html#identifiers).

This means that to refer to your `tabDefaultValue`, you need to use the following statement:

```
select * from _a66df261120b6c23."tabDefaultValue";
```

Note that the quotes are around the table name only, if you quote `dbname.tablename` together, this will be considered a single identifier with a dot in the middle.